# Using more bandwidth when sending video in 480p than in 720p with Gstreamer

Tags: networking, network-programming, gstreamer

I'm building an application where I used gstreamer to do the transmission of a video. My pipeline is really simple : I get the video from my application, convert it, encode in h264, build RTP packets, and send it through UDP. It works perfectly fine.
However, during testing I've remarked something strange: I use more bandwidth (i look at the bandwidth used with iptraf) when the video is sent in the 640 * 480 px than in 1280 * 720 px. As the video is higher in quality in the second case, I would suppose that it will use more bandwidth. Any idea why this happens? Thanks!

I just put here pipeline I use for you to test if you want :
sender :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency noise-reduction=10000 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay config-interval=0 pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000'
```

receiver :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 lowres=2 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

bandwidth use in 640 * 480 px : around 2000 kb/s

bandwidth use in 1280 * 720  px : around 1100 kb/s